# Using MongoDB without a server

Tags: reactjs, mongodb, axios

Do I need a server to use a mongoDB database?

Can I post data by just using axios?

```
axios
        .post(`https://lq-time-tracking.firebaseio.com/user.json`, values)
        .then(function(response) {})
        .catch(function(error) {
          console.log(error);
        });
```

I would like to use mongodb instead of firebase...

Comment: you need a server without server you can not post data

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot directly post data to a MongoDB. You need to create a server which will perform operations on a MongoDB (or any other DB) for you. If you are a Javascript guy then a recommended setup for you would be to have a Node JS Server with mongoose dependency. Inside this server you need to write your logic for saving your data. Let me know if you need a boiler plate for this.

Comment: I have created the server, but now I am getting a new error, you can see the question as follows: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/59012908/posting-to-mongodb